# Using Vimeo api, trying to pause all videos on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, iframe, vimeo

Got a page located here: http://www.friedmanllp.com/experienced_hires_people2.php

Attempting to pause all videos on page. I've used a slightly modified version of the following code taken from here: http://vimeo.com/forums/api/topic:44202

```
$(window).load(function() {
    //HERE IS THE SIMPLE CODE THAT WORKS
    var f = $('iframe'),
    url = f.attr('src').split('?')[0];
    // postMessage
    function post(action, value) {
        var data = { method: action };

        if (value) {
            data.value = value;
        }

        f.each(function(){this.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), url);});
    }

    // Play & Pause 
    $('.playerpause').click(function() {
        post('pause');
    });

    if (window.addEventListener){
        window.addEventListener('message', onMessageReceived, false);
    } else { // IE
        window.attachEvent('onmessage', onMessageReceived, false);
    }
});
```

and here's the element the click is attached to:

```
    <td height="38" valign="top" class="people_name2 playerpause"><a id="name1">Name 1</a></td>
```

and here's the iframe element (there are five total on the page):

```
    <iframe class="player" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/71894493?color=6da2de?api=1&title=1&byline=0&portrait=0" width="398" height="224" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

A bunch of errors show up in the console which I can't seem to solve. The videos do play just fine, but they won't pause.

Does anyone have any thoughs?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Froogaloop](https://github.com/vimeo/froogaloop) API, meant to make the interaction with the player easy. I'm sure you will find an easy way to do what you want using that API.